# Accessing WFS from Geobasis NRW with QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs

I am trying to access a WFS-Layer with QGIS and no matter what I do the result is nothing I can work with.

The WFS is this one: https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-existierende-bodennutzung_alkis.
It is provided on this webpage: https://www.bezreg-koeln.nrw.de/geobasis-nrw/webdienste/geodatendienste

I am using QGIS-Version 3.16.5-Hannover.

My first approach was to add the layer with Add WFS-Layer. This results in a polygon layer with an attribute table without the information I need, in this case, the soil usage (Bodennutzung).

[image]

Another approach was the extension WFS 2.0 Client which ends in this error message:

OWS Exception returned from the WFS:

> Request rejected due to errors. InternalExceptionCode:
> iiOperationParsingFailed. Reason: The attribute "count" for GetFeature
> is syntactically invalid.

[image]

I tried many different FeatureLimits but it won't work.

Did anyone else experience difficulties of this kind? Or does anyone have a solution?

Comment: The `ExistingLandUseObject` Feature is a complex type, so I think you will need the GMLAS plugin to access all data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick scan of the GML being returned those fields are deliberately set to `Nil` with a reason of "other:unpopulated" - so its working as designed but there is no data in those fields. You'll need to contact the data supplier to find out why

I used:

```
curl 'https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-existierende-bodennutzung_alkis?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=elu:ExistingLandUseObject&COUNT=50000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&BBOX=356545.05413687531836331,5694664.01414350606501102,356677.89285528962500393,5694755.6915688905864954,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&NAMESPACES=xmlns(elu,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/elu/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(elu,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/elu/4.0)' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 QGIS/33201/Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS'  --compressed | less
```

which I copied out of the QGIS network activity logger/